# Change Heading Level based on whether knitting to pdf or docx in RMarkdown

Tags: pdf, r-markdown, knitr, docx

I have a large project which contains several chapters (or children) which I can knit successfully as a pdf or docx.

Here is the `master.Rmd` which knits the children `chapterOne.Rmd`

````
---
title: Title of My Project
author: "My Name"
csl: G:/My Drive/ZoteroRPlugin/styles-master/spectroscopy-letters.csl
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: styles/preamble.tex #not relevant to the question
    keep_tex: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
    number_sections: yes
  word_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    toc: yes
    reference_docx: styles/word-styles-reference_05.docx
link-citations: yes
documentclass: styles/thesis-umich3
bibliography: G:/My Drive/ZoteroRPlugin/Report_references.bib
---

```{r global_options, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.align='center')
use_betterbiblatex = TRUE
```

\chapter{Introduction}
<!--# Introduction -->
```{r child = 'chapterOne.Rmd'}
```
\pagebreak

\chapter{Literature Review}
```{r child = 'chapterTwo.Rmd'}
```
\pagebreak
````

And here is the code for one of the children files `chapterOne.Rmd`.

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r chapter1_options, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.align='center')
use_betterbiblatex = TRUE
```

## Level 1 Heading

Insert Text Here

### Level 2 Heading
````

But in order for the headings to be done correctly I need to increase the heading level when knitting to docx (this is due to the csl file I need to use). Since the command `\chapter{Introduction}` is not recognized (which is fine).

Here is a screenshot when uploading to `docx` which gives me the proper headings
[image: img]

However this causes the `pdf` to be incorrectly leveled.

I realize that I could `Ctrl+H` and to a `Find/Replace` for `##` to `#` but this is not optimal to do everytime I have to switch between knitting to pdf vs docx. 
[image: img]

Does anyone have any ideas on a work-around??

Comment: Please don't use screenshots to include code.

Comment: @tarleb I did this in order to make the question as clear as possible providing a minimalistic example. I have modified the question to address your comment. Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: Despite the example is not reproducible, I would define a `header()` function like this one `header = function(title) knitr::asis_output(paste0(if(isTRUE(knitr::is_latex_output())) '#', title))` and use `header('# Level 1 Heading')` inside a chunk. I think a pandoc filter could also do a similar job with a seamless workflow.